# Add day to dateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have dateTime variable and I would like to add one day if date is not the last day of month, but one day before the last.

```
endDate = newDate(2016, 8, 30);//create date for test
if (DateTime.DaysInMonth(endDate.Year, endDate.Month) == (int)31 && endDate.Day == (int)30)
    endDate.AddDays(1);
```

From debugger I can see that execution goes on `endDate.AddDays(1);` but `endDate` is still the same (`30.08.2016`) as if `AddDays` function doesn't work.
Anybody knows why?

Comment: It returns a result that you have to assign as a DateTime is a struct and is immutable. `endDate = endDate.AddDays(1);` Also if you checked out [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see that the method returns a DateTime instance.

Comment: missing assigning updated date in enddate back

Comment: Thank you, my mistake. I have missed that in documentation. I work mostly with other languages where similar function operates on same variable and automatically I had in mind that.

Answer (score 7):

`AddDays` does not change the date but returns a new date with the added days. So for `endDate` to change you must assign the output of the function to it:

```
var endDate = new DateTime(2016, 8, 30);
endDate = endDate.AddDays(1);
```

Comment: Might want to rethink this. Not all months have 31 days.

Answer (score 0):

It returns a result that you have to assign as a DateTime is a struct and is immutable. Also if you checked out [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx) you will see that the method returns a DateTime instance.

```
endDate = endDate.AddDays(1);
```

About your logic, you want to increment it by 1 date if its the day before the last day of the month. What you have now is wrong and could be better written like this:

```
// only increment if one day before last day of month
if ((DateTime.DaysInMonth(endDate.Year, endDate.Month) - 1) == endDate.Day)
    endDate = endDate.AddDays(1); // assign the returned value
```

Take the result from the last day and subtract 1 to get the day before the last day of the month. If that is equal to your date's current day of the month then increment by one.

Answer (score 0):

Not all months have 31 days.

Here's the updated piece of code:

```
    var endDate = new DateTime(2017, 2, 27);//create date for test
    var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(endDate.Year, endDate.Month);
    if(endDate.Day == daysInMonth - 1)
        endDate = endDate.AddDays(1);
```